# Is it possible to upload documents as json string without deserialization / serialization?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I know this is possible with Rest but would like to know if there is any way to upload `Documents` that are valid JSON only without the need to deserialize them and provide an `object`?

This is purely a performance optimization.  Our SQL query returns the `object` as JSON and would prefer not to have to deserialize it in .Net consuming resources to be able to upload to Azure Search.

After thinking through using a custom `JsonConverter` scenario where I store a string and retrieve it, I have dismissed that option as probably not worth while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the SDK does not support this scenario. You'd be better off writing a simple client to send your JSON to the REST API directly.